# Implementing Perceptron with an array error

Tags: python, neural-network, perceptron

My question is if there was an issue in changing  `def step(self,x)` function since the original was faulty.

I attempted to change `def step(self,x)` to `x.any`. It resulted in a prediction error where all predictions were 1 I attempted to implement an OR Perceptron neural network from a book by following the codes given. However, I received an error `The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

This is the code:

```
from nn import Perceptron
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
print(X[1])
y = np.array([0],[1],[1],[0])

print("[INFO] training perceptron...")
p = Perceptron(X.shape[1],alpha = 0.1)
p.fit(X,y,epochs=20)

print("[INFO] testing perceptron...")

for (x,target) in zip(X,y):
    pred=p.predict(X)
    print("[INFO] data={}, ground-truth={}, pred={}". format(x, target[0], pred))
```

The package that I imported was:

```
import numpy as np

class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self, N, alpha = 0.1):
        self.W = np.random.randn(N+1)/np.sqrt(N)
        self.alpha  = alpha

    def step(self,x):
        if x>0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

    def fit(self, X, y, epochs = 10):
        X = np.c_[X,np.ones((X.shape[0]))]
        for epoch in np.arange(0, epochs):
            for (x,target) in zip(X,y):
                p = self.step(np.dot(x, self.W))
                if p!= target:
                    error = p-target
                    self.W += -self.alpha * error * x

    def predict(self,X,addBias=True):
        X = np.atleast_2d(X)
        if addBias:
            X=np.c_[X, np.ones((X.shape[0]))]

        return self.step(np.dot(X,self.W))
```

My apologies if its a silly question as I spent the whole day thinking about it to no avail.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The error that you are facing is because step() is coded to evaluate 1 element of the array at a time but when you pass an array to it in the predict function it has to do something like this:

```
[0.266,1.272,-1.282,0.889] > 1
```

The interpreter doesn't know which value to evaluate since it's an array and hence gives the error. Using any or all would check for 'any' or 'all' value in the array and give you 0 or 1 correspondingly, which is why you get an array of 1s when you write x.any().

Another thing that bothered me about the code you imported was that the forward pass is done in a loop, which is not very efficient or pythonic. A vectorized implementation is way better. I have changed the step function and fit function in that imported code to be vectorized and it runs fine for me.

```
 import numpy as np

class Perceptron:
    def __init__(self, N, alpha = 0.1):
        self.W = np.random.randn(N+1)/np.sqrt(N)
        self.alpha  = alpha

    def step(self,x):
        return 1. * (x > 0)

    def fit(self, X, y, epochs = 10):
        X = np.c_[X,np.ones((X.shape[0]))]
        for epoch in np.arange(0, epochs):
            Z = np.dot(X, self.W)
            p = self.step(Z)
            if np.any(p != y):
                error = (p-y)
                self.W += -self.alpha * np.dot(X.T,error)

    def predict(self,X,addBias=True):
        X = np.atleast_2d(X)
        if addBias:
            X=np.c_[X, np.ones((X.shape[0]))]

        return self.step(np.dot(X,self.W))
```

Now the step function is returning a binary array where the value is 1 when the input is greater than 0 else 0. For example if you had an array say:

```
X= [0.266,1.272,-1.282,0.889]
```

would be converted to:

```
[1,1,0,1]
```

I also changed the fit function so that it does everything vectorized.

One other thing that I did to my code was this :

Instead of

```
y = np.array([0],[1],[1],[0])
```

I did

```
y = np.array([0,1,1,0])
```

to get it working. I hope this helps. Be sure to ask anything if you don't understand.